# Google App Engine Python using POST method in MainPage

Tags: python-2.7, webapp2

I am trying to understand an issue with Google App Engine and Python.  It appears that I cannot have a POST handler in the MainPage class.  Or, I am somehow using it incorrectly.  The system does not object to the Python code but does not seem to find the post method.  The response from the server is "405 Method Not Allowed" and "The method POST is not allowed for this resource. "

The output on the dev_appserver.py console is

> INFO     2018-11-14 13:41:32,104 module.py:861] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 267
>
> INFO     2018-11-14 13:41:35,550 module.py:861] default: "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 188

The original source is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import webapp2
import logging

form = """ 
<form  action="/" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">Car<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(form)    # write the blank form

    def post(self):
        logging.info("in MainPage>post")
        self.response.write("Thanks! That works !!!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

The GET method is invoked correctly and the simple form is displayed properly.  The 405 error appears when I make a selection and submit the form.  I have declared the form with both;

```
<form  action="/" method="post">
```

and

```
<form  method="post">
```

I can create an additional class that can contains a POST method and have action select the other class; everything works fine.  I just have not found any logical reason it cannot correctly function in MainPage.

Comment: Try `<form action="" method="post">`

Comment: No difference.  <form action="" ...> still generates a "405 Method Not Allowed"

Comment: Check the source code in the browser.  You may have the old `action=""` cached.  Restart your dev machine.

Comment: I have flushed the buffers.  I have even switched machines.  No change.  So far POST only operates in a handler class other than MainPage.  But NOT when the POST method is implemented in the MainPage class.

Comment: show the source code in the browser. (view source)

Comment: Your code seems to be working just fine for me - at least on the devserver.